# DQN stuck at suboptimal policy in Atari Pong task

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I am in the process of implementing the DQN model from scratch in PyTorch with the target environment of Atari Pong. After a while of tweaking hyper-parameters, I cannot seem to get the model to achieve the performance that is reported in most publications (~ +21 reward; meaning that the agent wins almost every volley).

My most recent results are shown in the following figure. Note that the x axis is episodes (full games to 21), but the total training iterations is ~6.7 million.

[image]

The specifics of my setup are as follows:

#### Model

```
class DQN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, outputs):
        super(DQN, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=in_channels, out_channels=32, kernel_size=8, stride=4)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=4, stride=2)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3, stride=1)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features=64*7*7 , out_features=512)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(in_features=512, out_features=outputs)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv3(x))
        x = x.view(-1, 64 * 7 * 7)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x    # return Q values of each action
```

#### Hyperparameters

- batch size: 32
- replay memory size: 100000
- initial epsilon: 1.0
- epsilon anneals linearly to 0.02 over 100000 steps
- random warmstart episodes: ~50000
- update target model every: 1000 steps
- optimizer = optim.RMSprop(policy_net.parameters(),  lr=0.0025, alpha=0.9, eps=1e-02, momentum=0.0)

#### Additional info

- OpenAI gym Pong-v0 environment
- Feeding model stacks of 4 last observed frames, scaled and cropped to 84x84 such that only the "playing area" is visible.
- Treat losing a volley (end-of-life) as a terminal state in the replay buffer.
- Using [smooth_l1_loss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#smooth-l1-loss), which acts as Huber loss
- Clipping gradients between -1 and 1 before optimizing
- I offset the beginning of each episode with 4-30 no-op steps as the papers suggest

Has anyone had a similar experience of getting stuck around 6 - 9 average reward per episode like this?

Any suggestions for changes to hyperparameters or algorithmic nuances would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use PER prioritized experience replay.

This should definitely help you to get better score.

Also try batch_size bigger f. e. 64. (It can improve gradient)

Try learning rate anealing (decreasing over training time). (It could work).